# Adding an update to a Select Query

Tags: soql, update

I have the following query I'm running to fetch records where the `Order_Exported_to_A = False` and I want to update that field to True once that record is pulled.

`SELECT Name, SVMXC__Destination_Location__r.Account_Number__c, SVMXC__Destination_Location__r.A_Ship_to__c,    Customer_PO__c, (SELECT Product_Code__c, SVMXC__Expected_Quantity2__c, Line_Cost__c, SVMXC__Line_Price2__c FROM SVMXC__RMA_Shipment_Line__r) FROM SVMXC__RMA_Shipment_Order__c WHERE Order_Exported_to_A__c=false and SVMXC__Order_Status__c='Open' ORDER BY Name`

So, I want to include an update, something like: `UPDATE SVMXC__RMA_Shipment_Order__c SET Order_Exported_to_A__c=True` . How can I accomplish the update, or can I accomplish that within the select query?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78429/discussion-on-question-by-allideacon-adding-an-update-to-a-select-query).

Comment: Just a note on the format here, this is a **Question and Answer** site. You have posted a `Question`, but not really asked anything. Please always include at least on sentence in your `Question` posts which ends in a question mark. And *"Can anyone help me?"* doesn't count, it'll just get you downvotes. Think along the lines of "How do I ... ?"

Comment: @AdrianLarson I updated, I hope that clears up what I'm asking :) Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOQL is a query language. It has no support for operations besides Read. If you want to perform other CRUD operations, you will need to make different calls. Within Apex, that would look like:

```
List<MyObject__c> records = [SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c WHERE ...];
for (MyObject__c record : records)
{
    // set some fields
}
update records;
```

It would be a similar process if trying to do the same from an external service.